# Return value firestore onSnapshot in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I have a [onSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) query in a function:

```
//firebaseutil.js
export async function getShorts(uid) {
const q = query(collection(db, 'shorted'), where('owner', '==', uid));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
const urls = [];
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  urls.push({
    url: doc.data().url,
    shorturl: doc.data().shorturl,
    hits: doc.data().hits,
  });
});
console.log(urls);
return urls;
});
}
```

Which correctly logs the data and relogs it if I change the data on the firestore's collection (as expected)

I am trying to access these data from a user dashboard this way:

```
//dashboard.js
import { getShorts } from '../lib/fbutils';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [myurls, setUrls] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchShorts = async () => {
      if (user) {
        const urls = await getShorts(user.uid);
        setUrls(urls);
        console.log(myurls);
        console.log(urls);
      }
    };
    fetchShorts();
  }, []);
```

`user.id` is correctly set, whereas both `urls` and `myurls` are logged as undefined (I was thinking at least for a Promise pending)

what is wrong here? I usually use this pattern to retrieve data, but it's my first time I get data from a firestore subscription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#onsnapshot_5) does not return a promise and your `getShorts()` function returns before the data is received. You can return a promise from that function as shown below:

```
let fetched = false; 

export function getShorts(uid) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'shorted'), where('owner', '==', uid));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      const urls = querySnapstho.docs.map((d) => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }))
      
      if (!fetched) {
        // URLs fetched for first time, return value
        fetched = true;
        resolve(urls);
      } else {
        // URLs fetched already, an update received.
        // TODO: Update in state directly
      }
    })
  }) 
}
```

This should return all the URLs when you call the function `await getShorts(user.uid);` but for the updates received later, you'll have to update them in the state directly because the promise has resolved now.

Comment: Thank you @Dharmaraj , it was what i was thingking, but i wasnt able to sort it out... this means that using the snapshot this way is almost useless? should i place all the snapshot code directly in my component?

Comment: @popeating `onSnapshot()` is useful when you want to receive realtime updates. It does return data matching your query at first as well but it's easier to to use `setState()` when using this instead of returning the value. Also use `get()` instead if you want to fetch data only once.